# Where to find good PM documentation?

Tags: books, documentation, rup

I'm currently working as project lead(prince2 certified) since a few months and find it very interesting to see how other PMs solve problems, react to situations, use tools, etc.

StackExchange is very interesting and really helpful on this but do you know other interesting sources of information that are high quality and relevant for day to day situations for a PM?

I'm following some blogs like these:

- [pmhut.com](http://www.pmhut.com)
- [www.scrumalliance.org](http://www.scrumalliance.org)
- [fearnoproject.com](http://www.fearnoproject.com)

are there other blogs, rss or even other sources you recommend.

I also have access to a lot of digital books, so interesting title or authors to follow are very welcome as well. 
Little side note: I already know Prince2, PMBok, RUP so the basic study books aren't needed anymore.

In my current situation (consultant) I'm working with RUP (from IBM) so specific info on that is also welcome.

Also it would be good to have recommendations on audio books that are good to listen to in the car, while driving to work on these topics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the following links quite useful;

1. [Best Management Practice](http://www.best-management-practice.com/)
2. [Alchemy for Managers](http://www.alchemyformanagers.co.uk)

You can download PRINCE2 Training Material in the following training site:

http://www.prince2-ug.be/training-manual

Moreover, as mentioned ILM there are very good groups in Linkedin that could help you out depending on your area of interest

- Agile Project Management Group

Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 2):

There are several PM groups on LinkedIn that may be useful - I'm a member of:

- Project Management Link - www.pmlink.org
- The Project Manager Network - #1 Group for Project Managers

and I know there are many others. If you're not on LinkedIn, it might be worth joining. Some of the discussion can be a bit heavy and tedious, but there are nuggets of gold in there too.

Comment: I also found this link...  http://exm.nr/ePean7 which appears to provide a stack of podcasts. I can't vouch for the quality of the information provided as I have not listened to any of it, but it might be worth investigating.

Comment: that's a great link! thx

Answer (score 2):

Try Agile Alliance:
http://www.agilealliance.org/resources/articles/

Answer (score 1):

The PMI has many great practice guides available in digital form. They are free to PMI members e.g. on estimating, risk management, etc.

For audio in the car, try some of the project management podcasts available like Cornelius Fichtner's [pmpodcast](http://www.project-management-podcast.com/) or [pm411.org](http://pm411.org/).