# Good podcasts on current project management?

Tags: education

Can you recommend some good downloadable podcasts on project management? Either theory or current issues?

Comment: This question polls for a list of things. This is not a good fit for Stack Exchange and has been closed as part of our site-scope and quality improvement discussions on [meta].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've asked quite a similar question some time ago on '[where to find good information](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/965/where-to-find-good-pm-documentation)'

I personally listen to these podcasts:
http://www.project-management-podcast.com/

They do interviews with authors of books concerning PM (leadership, presentations, methodology, etc.)

and some other podcasts are :

- [People and projects podcast](http://www.peopleandprojectspodcast.com)
- [PM411.org](http://pm411.org/)
- [The PMO podcast](http://www.botinternational.com/thepmopodcast.htm)
- [The agile podcast](http://www.agilepodcast.com/)
- [the agile toolkit podcast](http://agiletoolkit.libsyn.com/)

on scrum:

- http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HanselminutesPodcast23ScrumAndScrumResources.aspx
- http://www.richard-banks.org/2008/06/scrum-podcast-ken-schwaber-talking-with.html
- http://www.botinternational.com/thepmopodcast_032.htm
- http://www.theagilerevolution.com/ **Weekly podcast on evolution on Scrum / added on 15 Sept. 2011**

Everybody owning an iPhone, iPod or iPad should definitely check out the [iTunes U](http://www.apple.com/education/itunes-u/whats-on.html) (university). 
It is filled with great courses of all leading universities on any topic you want.

Comment: I was also going to suggest The Project Management Podcast. You might want to put some more detail in your question. There are a lot of podcasts out there.

Comment: if you know others, feel free to contribute...