# First time project lead for web development. Need resources

Tags: software-development

I work for a small company and am usually tasked with front-end things such as design/UI/UX with some light php/mysql/ajax/javascript programming. I have done some pseudo-project management in the past for some small-scale projects but have a larger project looming. I was informed that I am going to be heading up a project in a few weeks and was wondering if anyone had useful resources on someone just starting a mid-sized project management 
I was just informed

Comment: To what tools do you have access at your company? What are the methods or frameworks that are used? (eg: agile, scrum, project manager, kanban, waterfall, versioning)

Comment: Forgive the delayed response. I've had a busy day. We do a modified version of waterfalling. I read a book on the agile method (Lean Software Development: An Agile Toolkit by Mary/Tom Poppendieck) and really like it. I may try to move towards something like that if its feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a big fan of Mike Cohn's writings.  I came from a Web development background (.NET development) to a more of a BA role.  His books and Website really helped me navigate the terrain.  It is well written and logically organized.

http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com

Comment: Yes, he does indeed have a good book called: Agile Estimating and Planning. Very good book to get to know agile in generale and how to plan and estimate.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps one of the things you can start doing is getting to know the different methods and frameworks that exist:

**Scrum** :

- [The Scrum guide](http://www.scrum.org/scrumguides)
- [What and who to follow?](http://www.kennethvr.be/blog/2011/08/19/scrum-resources-what-and-who-to-follow/)

**Kanban** :

- [Kanban applied to software development](http://www.infoq.com/articles/hiranabe-lean-agile-kanban)
- [Kanban vs Scrum](http://www.crisp.se/henrik.kniberg/Kanban-vs-Scrum.pdf)

To improve your development and programming itself, or that of your colleagues, I want to recommend my personal bibles: 
[Code complete 2](http://www.cc2e.com/) and [The pragmatic programmer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/020161622X)

This book helped me a lot and improved my coding the most over the years.

**Podcasts** on PM can be found in a previously asked question:

[Good podcasts on current project management?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/good-podcasts-on-current-project-management/2646#2646)

**Tools**: Take a look at tools to use like Jira with grasshopper plugin, MS Project, the good old whiteboard, ...

Comment: Completely agree with Code Complete.  Such an amazing, well written resource.